# Reducing redundant window code

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have 9 buttons in a custom WPF control that create and show 9 different windows.
This custom control is on every window in the application.
In the button_click event of each button I use the same logic. The only difference is the first and fourth lines that instantiate the window. The below code times 9 buttons times 11 windows = alot of redundant code.

```
private void btnNav11_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
    Robot windowRobot = new Robot( Translations.CheckLanguage( ) );
    toggleNavMenu(true);
    this.Hide();
    windowRobot.ShowDialog();
    this.Show();
    ChangeLanguage( Translations.CheckLanguage( ) );
    windowRobot.Close( );
}
```

So I refactored it down to each click event would pass a string to a method and it would create the window:

```
public static void showAlarmHistory() {
    showNewWindow( "AlarmHistory" );
}

public static void showNewWindow( string windowType ){   
    Window newWindow = CreateWindow( windowType );
    newWindow.ShowDialog();
    newWindow.Close();
}


public static Window CreateWindow( string windowToOpen ){
    Window openWindow = null;
    switch( windowToOpen ) {
        case "AlarmHistory":
            openWindow = new AlarmHistory( Translations.CheckLanguage() );
            break;
  ...
  ...
}
```

The above code all worked as expected but it wasn't a huge refactoring gain as this code was still duplicated in each of the windows code behinds.

As a next step I created a static class in the project to hold all of this code and called the class in each of the windows. (above code is the actual code snippet from the static class that I pasted from) It hasn't worked quite as well and I don't know how to make it right.

What happens is the calling window doesn't close. The windows open but they never close and the open windows keep stacking up.

Hope I was clear and concise enough. Any suggestions? I appreciate the help very much.

Jeff

Comment: Keep track of your open window(s) somewhere. If you only want to have one window open at a time, track that one window in a field/property of type Window. Before you open a new Window, look at the field/property, and if it contains a Window object, close that Window object. Then strore the newly opened window in that same field/property.

Comment: This is really more of a code review question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: elganzo, I took your suggestion and tweaked a little and got it to work by passing a reference of the parent window into the child and if the reference wasn't the "Main" window I close it. It works quite nicely thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: mydogisbox, I didn't realize there was a codereview section, thanks for the info I have signed up for that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a suggestion. First, create a base class:

```
public class MyWindow : Window
{
}
```

Now derive all your other windows from this one:

```
public class AlarmHistory : MyWindow
{
    // Your AlarmHistory window logic stuff here
}

public class OtherHistory : MyWindow
{
    // Your Other windows logic stuff here
}
```

Now change your `showAlarmHistory()` function:

```
public static void showAlarmHistory() {
    //showNewWindow( "AlarmHistory" );
    showNewWindow(new AlarmHistory(Translations.CheckLanguage()));
}
```

And finally change your `showNewWindow()` function:

```
public static void showNewWindow( MyWindow window ){   
    window.ShowDialog();
    window.Close();
}
```

What you are doing here is just creating a new Window. Your `showNewWindow()` function shouldn't care what kind it is. It just does whatever it needs to. You can put common custom methods inside of the `MyWindow` class. And you can cast it to a specific window, if you need to.

Comment: This seemed to work in the same way; the windows keep stacking up. The trouble is that the current window.Close() never gets called before the new window is opened. Although, you did take me down a road that enabled me to move alot of the redundant code to the new window base class which now gets inherited by all of my other windows. Thanks for that.